# I am trying to create a View in SQL server 2000 using the Enterprise Managers

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, sql-server-2000

I am trying to creat a View in SQL server 2000 using the Enterprise Manager that some times doesn't return any rows and when it doesn't i need it to return a 0.
I have tried this but I keep getting this message when I try to save it:

> The Query Designer does not support
>   the IF SQL construct.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT     dbo.oehdrhst_sql.cus_no, dbo.oehdrhst_sql.inv_dt, dbo.oehdrhst_sql.inv_no, dbo.OELINHST_SQL.item_no, 
                                          dbo.OELINHST_SQL.item_desc_1, dbo.OELINHST_SQL.item_desc_2, dbo.OELINHST_SQL.qty_to_ship, dbo.IMITMIDX_SQL.user_def_fld_1, 
                                          dbo.IMITMIDX_SQL.user_def_fld_2, dbo.IMITMIDX_SQL.user_def_fld_3, dbo.IMITMIDX_SQL.user_def_fld_4, 
                                          dbo.IMITMIDX_SQL.user_def_fld_5, dbo.oehdrhst_sql.ord_type, dbo.oehdrhst_sql.orig_ord_type, dbo.OELINHST_SQL.qty_return_to_stk, 
                                          dbo.OELINHST_SQL.qty_to_ship * dbo.IMITMIDX_SQL.user_def_fld_2 AS extended, CONVERT(datetime, STR(dbo.oehdrhst_sql.inv_dt, 8, 0)) 
                                          AS [Date]
                    FROM         dbo.oehdrhst_sql INNER JOIN
                                          dbo.OELINHST_SQL ON dbo.oehdrhst_sql.ord_no = dbo.OELINHST_SQL.ord_no INNER JOIN
                                          dbo.IMITMIDX_SQL ON dbo.OELINHST_SQL.item_no = dbo.IMITMIDX_SQL.item_no
                    WHERE     (dbo.oehdrhst_sql.inv_dt BETWEEN 20100701 AND 20110630) AND (dbo.OELINHST_SQL.item_no BETWEEN '3065 0' AND 
                                          '3065 ZZZZZZZZZZ') AND (NOT (dbo.IMITMIDX_SQL.user_def_fld_2 IS NULL)))
SELECT     EXTENDED, cus_no, inv_dt, inv_no, item_no, item_desc_1, item_desc_2, qty_to_ship, user_def_fld_1, user_def_fld_2, [date]
 FROM         (SELECT     dbo.oehdrhst_sql.cus_no, dbo.oehdrhst_sql.inv_dt, dbo.oehdrhst_sql.inv_no, dbo.OELINHST_SQL.item_no, 
                                               dbo.OELINHST_SQL.item_desc_1, dbo.OELINHST_SQL.item_desc_2, dbo.OELINHST_SQL.qty_to_ship, 
                                               dbo.IMITMIDX_SQL.user_def_fld_1, dbo.IMITMIDX_SQL.user_def_fld_2, dbo.IMITMIDX_SQL.user_def_fld_3, 
                                               dbo.IMITMIDX_SQL.user_def_fld_4, dbo.IMITMIDX_SQL.user_def_fld_5, dbo.oehdrhst_sql.ord_type, dbo.oehdrhst_sql.orig_ord_type, 
                                               dbo.OELINHST_SQL.qty_return_to_stk, dbo.OELINHST_SQL.qty_to_ship * dbo.IMITMIDX_SQL.user_def_fld_2 AS extended, 
                                               CONVERT(datetime, STR(dbo.oehdrhst_sql.inv_dt, 8, 0)) AS [Date]
                        FROM          dbo.oehdrhst_sql INNER JOIN
                                               dbo.OELINHST_SQL ON dbo.oehdrhst_sql.ord_no = dbo.OELINHST_SQL.ord_no INNER JOIN
                                               dbo.IMITMIDX_SQL ON dbo.OELINHST_SQL.item_no = dbo.IMITMIDX_SQL.item_no
                        WHERE      (dbo.oehdrhst_sql.inv_dt BETWEEN 20100701 AND 20110630) AND (dbo.OELINHST_SQL.item_no BETWEEN '3065 0' AND 
                                               '3065 ZZZZZZZZZZ') AND (NOT (dbo.IMITMIDX_SQL.user_def_fld_2 IS NULL))) a
 GROUP BY EXTENDED, cus_no, inv_dt, inv_no, item_no, item_desc_1, item_desc_2, qty_to_ship, user_def_fld_1, user_def_fld_2, [date] ELSE
                            SELECT     EXTENDED = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably drop the IF EXISTS portion and just use an ISNULL(EXTENDED,0). That assumes a lot though.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you should do in the view.  Instead do it when you CALL the view, i.e.:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM v_MyView) > 0
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM v_MyView
END 
ELSE
SELECT 0
```